# Erro ao iniciar serviço no arranque(ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Tags: android, android-service

estou com um problema para iniciar um service no android logo quando o celular liga segui vários tutoriais porém sempre ocasiona esse erro

> 06-04 23:56:27.305 10948-10948/pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall, PID: 10948
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall.YouWillNeverDestroy.StartServiceBoot: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall/.YouWillNeverDestroy.MyService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2368819 u0a298 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3216)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6520)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall/.YouWillNeverDestroy.MyService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2368819 u0a298 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1521)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1477)
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
>           at pluswallpapers.devmarques.com.wallpapersall.YouWillNeverDestroy.StartServiceBoot.onReceive(StartServiceBoot.java:15)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3209)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6520) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

A classe start boot é essa, tem tudo declarado certinho lá no manifest, o service, o startboot completed, acredito que possa ser algo para inicializar o serviço nesse classe do broadcast mas não sei como resolver...

```
public class StartServiceBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);        
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

}

lembrando que não é uma activity apenas um serviço em background, se o serviço é startado por uma activity funciona normalmente, acredito que eu deva estar infringindo algo da segurança do android para não inicializar no broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso tem a ver com as [limitações impostas pelo Android 8 à execução de serviços em *background*](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).
Estes serviços apenas podem ser lançados se a aplicação se encontrar em *foreground*

A documentação sugere que use um *foreground service*(`startForegroundService()` em vez de `startService()`, ou um *scheduled job*.

[Este artigo](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/12/action_boot_completed-intentservice-android-8p0.html) do CommonsWare sugere ainda o uso do método [goAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#goAsync()).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, nem imaginava que esse seria o problema, @Ramaral como eu já vi você respondendo bastante coisa relacionada a android, e vejo que você tem entendimento, você teria algum site que explique bem como funciona o service, a execução dele em segundo plano?

Comment: Comece pela [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background), ela lhe dará uma visão geral. Quando compreender os princípios ser-lhe-á fácil, depois, saber procurar/perguntar por aspectos mais particulares.

Comment: Para serviços iniciados no manifest, como por exemplo... <service
            android:name="com.parse.fcm.ParseFirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
como posso definir para ser em foreground?

Comment: *"Para serviços iniciados no manifest"* - Isso não existe. Os [serviços](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#top_of_page) são iniciados por uma aplicação ou serviço.