# Notificações no Android param após tempo de inatividade no app

Tags: android, push-notification, api, firebase-cloud-messaging

Utilizamos as notificações tanto do *OneSignal* como do *Firebase* para notificar prestadores de serviços do nosso app, sobre novos pedidos para serem atendidos em tempo real.

Notamos que acontece mesmo que o app rodando com um `service` em `foreground`para rodar mesmo que o usuário ou o android mate a aplicação, alguns `push notifications` não são recebidos depois de um tempo de inatividade no app.

Após que é aberto o app, ainda demora um tempo para receber novas notificações. Alguma sugestão do que seja?

Comment: Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304492/2541)

Comment: Oi @ramaral, eu vi que alguns aparelhos de celulares, também limitam o auto inicio de alguns apps, você tem ou sabe algo a respeito disso?

Comment: Consegue ser mais especifico? Como é feito o "auto inicio"? Se for através de um serviço a razão é(pode ser) a mesma.

Comment: veja isso https://onesignal.com/blog/manufacturers-interfere-with-reliable-notifications/

Comment: Sim, dai eu ter colocado o "pode ser" e não apenas é.

Answer (score -3):

Falando do Firebase algo que pode estar acontecendo é o que diz [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-ondeletedmessages) na documentação oficial. Você já criou o tratamento pro método onDeletedMessages?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).